# Remove data containing string from object

Tags: javascript

I want to ask how do I remove strings from data. Lets say I have a data:

```
var data = {DeviceID: "101", ManufacturerID: "9", ManufacturerName: "Toshiba", Device Name: "Toshiba - Tecra R950", Price: "200"};
```

how do I remove `ManufacturerName` and `Device Name` because they do not have numbers?

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: you'll have to try to convert each value into integer and then if it succeed, add it to a new object, and finally, discard the old object and use the new one

Comment: That's also not JSON.

Comment: May i know how to convert the object to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method - if you're happy with mutating the object rather than creating a new one - is to [iterate over the object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), and try to coerce each value to a number. If it's not a number remove the property.

```js
const data = { DeviceID: '101', ManufacturerID: '9', ManufacturerName: "Toshiba", 'Device Name': 'Toshiba - Tecra R950', Price: '200' };

for (let key in data) {
  if (!Number(data[key])) delete data[key];
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Nice approach, Like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this-

```js
const data = {DeviceID: "101", ManufacturerID: "9", ManufacturerName: "Toshiba", DeviceName: "Toshiba - Tecra R950", Price: "200"};
const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).filter(([key, value]) => !isNaN(Number(value)))
);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.entries().filter(([key,value]) => !Number.isNaN(Number.parseInt(value))
```